# Query Amazon Redshift Database Through PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to query a `Amazon Redshift` database through `PHP` with `AWS SDK for PHP`, and if so, what classes would I include and what functions would I call? I'm having trouble finding the documentation for that on their site. I see documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-redshift.html) to use the `Factory` function within the `Aws\Redshift\RedshiftClient` class to log into the client object that is the Redshift database, but I don't see any documentation to query that database after you've connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would use the same method to query Redshift that you would to query a PostgreSQL database. You can't use the AWS SDK to query Redshift.

Comment: Ok, so I could connect to the database with `pg_connect()`, query with `pg_query()` & use the rest of the functions listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php?

Comment: Yes. Redshift is PostgreSQL compatible. Read this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is just wrong (or outdated). You absolutely can use the AWS PHP SDK to query Redshift using the `RedshiftDataAPIServiceClient`. You can [read the docs on that here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.RedshiftDataAPIService.RedshiftDataAPIServiceClient.html).